# Extract my JSON Result in Android

Tags: java, android, json, asynchronous, background

My JSon Array has been returned like

---

```
[
{"StudentID":"BS231",
"ChildName":"Vishesh Malhotra",
"ClassName":"4th Class",
"Attendance":false},

{"StudentID":"BS233",
"ChildName":"Anisha Malhotra",
"ClassName":"6th Class",
"Attendance":false
}
]
```

---

I want to extract it, I know i can put it into JSONObject to initialize, but while using optJSONArray function now i have no Array Name to extract

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray data  = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("ArrayNameWhichIsMissing");
```

kindly tell how can i extract that Array.

Comment: If you are new to JSON parsing, lookup for a library called `Jackson JSON Parser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ // json array node
    {  // json object node 
        "StudentID": "BS231", 
        "ChildName": "Vishesh Malhotra",
        "ClassName": "4th Class",
        "Attendance": false
    },
    {
        "StudentID": "BS233",
        "ChildName": "Anisha Malhotra",
        "ClassName": "6th Class",
        "Attendance": false
    }
]
```

You have a json array

```
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("myjsonstring");
for(int i =0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
   JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.get(i);
   String id = jb.getString("StudentID");
   Log.i(".......",id);
   // Similar for other ChildName and ClassName
   // use getBoolean for attendance 
}
```

Log output

```
....... BS231
....... BS233
```

Comment: Yes Raghunandan is right, I already have the JSONArray all i need was to just directly put into the JSONArray and use it

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get response as JSONArray also like this

```
JSONArray objj = new JSONArray("your json string");
```

comment me about result